# Pass function return as argument to regexp-opt in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to generate regexp's from a master list. An example list:

```
(setq name-and-keyword-list
      (list
      '("pFoo" ("foo" "bar" "baz"))
      '("pBar" ("apples" "pears" "orange"))))
```

`(regexp-opt '("foo" "bar" "baz"))` works and `(car (cdr name-and-keyword-list))`

returns `(("foo" "bar" "baz"))` which is almost the same argument I passed to `regexp-opt` manually.

Trying to combine everything into one call fails:

```
(regexp-opt (cdr(car name-and-keyword-list)))
```

returns `Wrong type argument: stringp, ("foo" "bar" "baz")`. Is there a different way I can access the list elements so that they are a valid argument for `regexp-opt`?

Comment: Here is one working example that uses regexp-opt, but I'm not sure whether it will help -- I use it to highlight keywords:  `(defvar lawlist-keywords (list (concat "\\b\\(?:" (regexp-opt (list "FIXME" "TO-DO" )) "\\)\\b") 0 'font-lock-warning-face t))`  And the variable `lawlist-keywords` goes inside the following:  `(font-lock-add-keywords 'lawlist-tex-mode (list lawlist-keywords ))`

Comment: This is similar to my first usage of `regexp-opt` above, where the argument is typed out. I want to pull the argument from a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fix:

```lisp
(setq name-and-keyword-list
      `(("pFoo" ("foo" "bar" "baz"))
        ("pBar" ("apples" "pears" "orange"))))

(regexp-opt (cadar name-and-keyword-list))
```

Comment: Is cadar a typo or perhaps defined in an extension? I get `Symbol's function definition is void` when attempting to use. I think you meant something equivalent to `(car (cdar` which seems to fix my problem. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: `cadar` is a sequence of `car`, `cdr` and `car`. You can apply them in this order to see how this
works. It becomes defined with `(require 'cl)`.

Comment: I can see that the outermost `(car` removes a set of parenthesis, but why does that make it a valid argument? `(type-of` returns "cons" for `(car name-...` `(cdar name-...` and `(cadar name-...`

Comment: They all are "cons". Lists are conses. And the final one is a list of strings.

Comment: abo-abo: Why did you use a backquote when nothing is being evaluated?

Comment: @phils, it's easier to find the quasi-quote on my keyboard:)